# How To visible Package A classes to Package B

Tags: rcp

In Eclipse RCP, Package A is dependent on Package B. Then How To visible Package A classes to Package B

Comment: If these packages are in different plugins you can't do this as it will give circular dependencies and you won't be able to build the RCP. You need to rework the class dependencies.

Comment: The package are in different plugin only. In First Plugin, there is a treeViewer and In Second Plugin, there is a registration form. so, treviewer is dependent on registration Form. when I pass value from registration form to treeviewer then TreeViewer class is not visible in Registration form.